# Delete duplicate rows and keep one row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This the name of my table Result_Simul

This is the value

```
       Pk   FkIdResult   FkIdSimul
       1        43         1244
       2        43         1244
       3        52         1244
       4        52         1244
```

How to keep just keep rows Pk=1 and Pk=3 and delete Pk=2 and Pk=4

Thanks for helping me.

Im not really good in Tsql

Frank

Comment: What version of sql-server are you on?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to give each duplicate an ascending number, and then delete the 2nd and higher duplicates:

```
delete  tbl
from    (
        select  row_number() over (partition by FkIdResult, FkIdSimul 
                                  order by Pk desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    YourTable
        ) tbl
where   rn > 1
```

[Working example at SE Data.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/64879/new)