# Delete values which are appeared more than one in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, distinct-values

I have a particular value that appears more than one time in a column of a table. I want to keep only one time for that record. How to do it? For example, from this table I want to keep 63 record for only one time. Please see the table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZlOL.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete duplicate rows and keep one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845046/delete-duplicate-rows-and-keep-one-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Row_Number()` to give each duplicate a number, then delete which ever holds a value more than one

```
  delete  tbl
    from    ( SELECT 
                *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
              PARTITION BY 
                row_number
              ORDER BY 
                Date) rn
    where   rn > 1
```

Comment: Hi Mustafa, I have 10 other dimensions and metrics, do i need to include all of it after PARTITION BY clause.

Comment: can explain with more details please ?

Comment: Please see the image. I have Date,Hour,Activity_Group_ID, Activity_ID, cost etc in the table.

Comment: you need to include in (PARTITION BY) clause the column that you do not want to have duplicate values.  which is up to you

Comment: Hi Mustafa, Thanks for help. I'm using bigquery. It shows unexpected keyword FROM.

Comment: before everything please  make sure that you have a copy of your data,  as DELETE can not be reverted,  and i think this link will be very helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130324/bigquery-delete-statement-to-remove-duplicates

Comment: Hi Mustafa, As I've already calculated the duplicate column. Please see the table.I want to keep 63 record for only one time.

Comment: "where   rn > 1"  this part deletes any record with count more than one, which means the record holding rn =1  will remain

Comment: Thank you. I think this query will help me. delete from t1 from 
      (SELECT *,row_number() OVER (          
              PARTITION BY 
                row_number
              ORDER BY 
                Date) rn from t1 
    where   rn > 1. but  still it shows the error.

Comment: @nrad . . . This does not look like correct MySQL syntax.  How can this be the accepted answer?